# Twitter Search Widget over SSL

Tags: php, javascript, ssl, twitter

I am trying get the twitter search widget to work on my SSL pages, without the browser throwing a warning about not encrypted. I have been searching a while now but cant find a solution. Any ideas?

I have tried the following:
[Including Twitter Widgets.js via HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846938/including-twitter-widgets-js-via-https)

my code is as follows

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="https://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'search',
  search: 'Search term',
  interval: 30000,
  title: 'Twitter feed',
  subject: 'WHatever',
  width: 295,
  height: 300,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: 'transparent',
      color: '#88afcc'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: 'transparent',
      color: '#cccccc',
      links: '#1868e0'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: true,
    live: true,
    behavior: 'default'
  }
}).render().start();
</script>
```

I have tried saving widget.js to my server and calling it with https that way but to no avail, also I tried changing all occurences of 'http' to 'https' in widget.js again to no avail.

Any ideas? I really want to keep this on the SSL pages but not at the cost of users thinking the connection between us and them is insecure.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the widget.js file to your https file directory and change your src to point to it.

The error is occurring because ANY file outside your https directory is not going to be encrypted by SSL.